# Assigning UIPickerView value issue on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I am facing this issue on device that assigning the selected row value of picker takes too much time to be shown on label while on simulator it works fine.

Below is the code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView == rewardsName) {

    NSString *selectedReward = [self.rewards objectAtIndex:row];

    if ([reward1.text length]==0){
        //set label 1

        reward1.text = selectedReward;
    }
    if ([reward2.text length]==0){
        //set label 2

        reward2.text = selectedReward;
    }
    if([reward3.text length]==0){
        //set label 3.

        reward3.text = selectedReward;
    }
    }

    else if(pickerView == selectNamazPicker){

        aNumberString = [self.namazArray objectAtIndex:row];

        NSLog(@"aNumberString:: %@", aNumberString);
    } 
}
```

Can anyone tell me what can be the issue ... I am unable to find one...

**

```
EDITED:
ISSUE RESOLVED:
```

**

```
For others who would face this issue.

I don't know whether it was creating the problem or not. But I did make these changes to my code.

In my .h file, previously I was just defining properties of UILabels (reward1, reward2 etc) with IBOutlet and not ivars. But then I defined ivars as IBOutlet UILabel reward1; etc and eliminated IBOutlet from properties then it started working fine. 

Now the problem has resolved.
```

Comment: what is `rewardsName` ? Note that you are comparing the addresses of two objects in : `if (pickerView == rewardsName)` ...

Comment: Actually I am using two pickerview on single view. rewardsName is a UIPickerview

Comment: If `reward1`, `reward2` and `reward3` are of class `UILabel`, reading and changing their text should have little effect.  Can you try: (1) commenting out this entire block to confirm that the problem disappears, and (2) change the UILabel text at some other point in your code to confirm that the problem appears there?

Comment: It's a good idea to have your IBOutlets as properties for memory management purposes - there are several SO questions about it. Your problem is almost certainly to do with something else.

Comment: Yes, but it is resolved now. i dont know what exactly the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who would face this issue.

I don't know whether it was creating the problem or not. But I did make these changes to my code.

In my .h file, previously I was just defining properties of UILabels (reward1, reward2 etc) with IBOutlet and not ivars. But then I defined ivars as IBOutlet UILabel reward1; etc and eliminated IBOutlet from properties then it started working fine.

Now the problem has resolved.